# AMD-V on MSI A75 Motherboard with AMD A8-3850 APU in BIOS

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation, amd-processor

Actually I want to run VMware Workstation on my Windows 8.1 PC but it says error that only AMD-V supports virtualization. But I am Unable to See/Use AMD-V on MSI A75 Motherboard with AMD A8-3850 APU in BIOS Settings Page.

Any solutions? I think I need to update the BIOS. 
Will that give me the option to enable AMD-V?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about AMD because I have always used Intel. But you can give a try.

Go to `Overclocking --> CPU Features --> X.M.P Support Information --> SVM`  . SVM should be enabled to leverage virtualization.

Have a look at this [page](http://www.legitreviews.com/msi-a75ma-g55-amd-socket-fm1-motherboard-review_1651/4) to find the same.

Comment: SVM Mode is enabled, but still I am getting error on VMware when I am running Mac on it. See My Screenshot - http://i.stack.imgur.com/bAcbR.jpg

Comment: Now automatically the OS gets started on VMware, but it shows error:

OS X Mavericks - VMware Workstation
---------------------------
[b]The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.[/b]


I implemented line from 
http://minhdanh2002.blogspot.in/2012/07/fixing-cpu-has-been-disabled-by-guest.html

cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101"

But it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808830/error-on-starting-os-x-mavericks-on-amd-a8-apu-with-radeon-hd-graphics

Comment: I am sorry :( but try this unlocker ...

http://www.mrxuri.com/2013/10/04/install-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-apple-system-in-vmware-virtual-machine.html