# Error on starting OS X Mavericks on AMD A8-APU with Radeon HD Graphics

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, vmware, vmware-workstation, amd-processor

I am getting the following error on starting OS X Mavericks -

VMware Workstation ---------------------------
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.

I implemented line from http://minhdanh2002.blogspot.in/2012/07/fixing-cpu-has-been-disabled-by-guest.html
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101" But it didn't work.

Comment: Why people are voting to close the question? Is the question Illegal?

Comment: There are better sites than SO to ask this question. it just isn't about programming....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run OS X in this configuration.  The Mavericks EULA specifies that Mavericks can only be virtualized on Apple hardware.  (This is true for any version of OS X whose EULA allows for virtualization.)